# Use ggplot2 to make a scatter of group means without preprocessing the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I can make the following plot very easily by computing the group means using `dplyr`, but is there way to do it entirely within `ggplot2` without preprocessing the data, using `stat_<something>`?

```
library(tidyverse)

iris |>
  group_by(Species) |>
  summarise(
    Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length),
    Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width)
  ) |> ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species))
```

`stat_summary` seems to summarize only at identical `x` or `y` values, and `stat_bin` doesn't work across discrete variables, but is there another `stat_*` for this? I've found `stat_centroid` from `ggh4x` but I'm looking for something built-in.

Edit: to be clear about my goals, I'm looking to avoid the duplication of the x/y/color column names if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get, I think, is to embed the aggregation inside the `stat_summary` call by using a function as the `data` [argument](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html#arguments), like

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
    stat_summary(data = function(df) aggregate(
        cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) ~ Species, data = df, FUN = mean
    ))
```

(using base aggregate)

or

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
    stat_summary(data = function(df) summarise(group_by(df, Species), 
        Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length), 
        Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width)
    ))
```

(using dplyr functions)

This will respect your inherited aes (x, y, color) and process the inherited data through the custom `aggregate` or `summarise` function. Which is pretty much what you were doing, just unpiped.

Inspired by [Allan Cameron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73845801/17732851) below, you could use dplyr's `summarise_all` to simply apply the summary function across all columns, retaining their names so that the x and y aes will be inherited (you still have to specify the grouping variable though):

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
+     stat_summary(data = function(df) summarise_all(group_by(df, Species), mean))
```

Note that this may fail if some of the columns are not numeric, so `summarise_if` might allow you to filter by condition:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
+     stat_summary(data = function(df) summarise_if(
          group_by(df, Species), is.numeric, mean
      ))
```

(`summarise_if` is technically deprecated, but for this pipeless use it's pretty handy)

Comment: Thanks! There's no way to avoid duplicating the column names, eh?

Comment: Depends... `aggregate` can be given a data.frame  `x` + a `by` argument instead of a formula, so you could use indices instead of column names (useful if you have a very large df), e.g. `aggregate(df[,1:2], by=list("Species" = df$Species), FUN=mean)`. But if you want to inherit them from the aes (group by whatever was assigned to x and y) I don't know if that is possible without writing a new `stat_*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a bit less code by realising that you can add a `list` of geom layers to a ggplot, so by doing:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(mean(Sepal.Length), mean(Sepal.Width), color = Species)) +
  lapply(split(iris, iris$Species), function(x) geom_point(data = x))
```

we get

[image]

An alternative would be to pass a little summary data frame to the points layer using `summarize_all`

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(data = summarize_all(group_by(iris, Species), mean))
```

[image]

Comment: Clever! I'd note, however, that ggplot still plots a point for each row in the original `iris` data. This could create issues if one wanted to use alpha transparency, for example.

Comment: @jdobres fair point. An alternative that avoids this is `summarize_all` - updated.